# Using Java with SleepyMongoose to perform MongoDB inserts

Tags: java, mongodb, httpurlconnection, sleepy-mongoose

this is my first post here.

In a nutshell, I've set up a MongoDB instance, and installed a REST service to run commands on it. The one I chose was SleepyMongoose.

I've been trying to write a simple Java program to do three things: a find, an insert, and another find. Basically, display the collection, insert something, and display it again to show the update. The finds work correctly, but the insert has been giving me trouble.

[The documentation of SleepyMongoose](https://github.com/10gen-labs/sleepy.mongoose/wiki/Inserting) uses curl with a data parameter, but I've been using Java's HttpURLConnection. How can I add that data parameter to the HttpURLConnection? Here's what I've been trying:

```
private static void POST (String command) {

try {
        // The 'command' is just going to be 'insert' for now.
        URL restURL = new URL(REST + DATABASE + "/" + COLLECTION + "/_" + command);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) restURL.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.connect();

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        String x = "docs=[{'x':1}]";
        out.write(x.getBytes());
        out.close();

        conn.disconnect();
    }

catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Uh oh...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Am I even using SleepyMongoose for its correct purpose? Are there better alternatives? I'm not tied down to any REST api, but I'd like to get the inserts down.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it only works if there's a reader attached to it, too. If I attach the following immediately after the write, it works perfectly:

```
String line, output = "";

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
    output += line;

rd.close();
```

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be writing similar code for an Android project and have had success with the below when doing a POST.

Note that the data you get back will need to be parsed as it comes in as a HttpResponse. I have been converting it to a String then pulling out JSON values (see below).

Sample insert:

```
String[] link2 = {"http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:27080/foo/bar/_insert", "[{\"x\":2},{\"x\":3}]"};
new HTTPPost().execute(link2);
```

Code for POST, yours will be different due to not writing for Android specifically. Replace AndroidHttpClient with HttpClient. Note the BasicNameValuePair used to specify "docs" as key.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
        String link = params[0];
        String value = params[1];
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(link);
        AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("docs", value));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            return client.execute(post);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }
```

To parse to string:

```
String test = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity());
```

To pull out JSON values:

```
public String parseJSON(String toParse)
{
    try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(toParse);
        String aJsonString = jObject.getString("ok");

        JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Pulling items from the array
                String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("link");
                return oneObjectsItem;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Oops
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return "";
}
```